# inserting labs() into a custom geom?

Tags: legend-properties

I know the topic of custom legends has been discussed here, but I'm trying to do a different thing here (or so I think)
I am building a custom geom for representing timeline of earthquakes.
Normally to have automatic legend in ggplot2 one would write (example):

> ggplot(aes(x = DATE,color = TOTAL_DEATHS,size = EQ_PRIMARY))

and this would result in 2 legends, one with title "TOTAL_DEATHS", one with "EQ_PRIMARY". If I wanted different legend names, I would use **labs(color="# Deaths",size="Richter scale")**

Is there a way to have the labs() options inside my custom geom (or inside a custom theme maybe)?, so I wouldn't have to specify it each time I make a plot?

I would greatly appreciate some insight on this.

Comment: Will `# Deaths` and `Richter scale` always be the lab names or changing depending on something?

Comment: At this point of my project these two (`# Deaths` and `Richter scale`) are going to be always the lab names.